# Привести указатель float в int

Tags: c++

Не понимаю как мне правильно преобразовать из указателя float* в int*

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float* fvalue = new float(15.5);
    std::cout << "[0x" << fvalue << "] " << *fvalue << std::endl;
    int* ivalue = reinterpret_cast<int*>(fvalue);
    std::cout << "[0x" << ivalue << "] " << *ivalue << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

На выходе программа выполняется так:

```
[0x0x55d5869fceb0] 15.5
[0x0x55d5869fceb0] 1098383360
```

Comment: А что вы хотите получить? Вы преобразовали, получили трактовку расположения в памяти `float` как `int`... Все верно.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<int*>(fvalue)` - правильно преобразовывает указатель. То, что полученный указатель потом нельзя будет разыменовать - это другое дело. *"На выходе программа выполняется так"* - а что ожиалось

Comment: Я хотел из этого указателя получить указатель на целое число)

Comment: Так я еще и не могу корректно перезаписывать эту область. Так как получается такие данные в итоге: 1.4013e-45

Comment: А вы прочитайте как реализован float и на что укажет в таком случаи int*. Нужно просто получить целое, так получайте  std::cout << "[0x" << fvalue << "] " << static_cast<int>( *fvalue )

Comment: Объясните если можете, я не понимаю. И там и там по 4 байта...

Comment: https://prog-cpp.ru/c-data-types/

Comment: Количество байт под переменную одинаковый (не обязательно!), но формат записи чисел `int` и `float` различается. Поэтому вам нужно не указатели приводить, а значения `int ivalue = *fvalue;`.

Comment: А нельзя я так понимаю не выделять новое место под это число? Вот к примеру хотелось бы выделить 4 байта памяти и использовать его как и для float так и для int в различных ситуациях.

Comment: А, так вам хочется [`union`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)... Только вот *одновременно* использовать и как то, и как другое (типа, записать float, потом int, потом прочитать записанный float) не получится. Как и не получится записать 15.5, а считать (без приведения типов) 15.

Comment: Идеально! Все решили) Я просто документ парсю, где могут быть и float и int числа. И не хочу выделять и под то и под другое память. Хочется 4 байта выделить и использовать эту область пока программа выполняется.

Comment: *"Я хотел из этого указателя получить указатель на целое число) "* - ну так вы его и получили